# C# DateTime.TryParseExact with optional parameters

Tags: c#, .net

The code below works fine, just wondering if there's a more elegant way of achieving the same thing? The dates below should be valid, anything other than that should not:

- 1/12/2017
- 1/12/2017 11:10
- 1/12/2017 11:10:30
- 15/5/2017
- 15/5/2017 11:10
- 15/5/2017 11:10:30
- 1/5/2017
- 1/5/2017 11:10
- 1/5/2017 11:10:30
- 25/12/2017
- 25/12/2017 11:10
- 25/12/2017 11:10:30

**In other words:** it should work with 1 and 2 digits days/months, and it should work with and without time, including or not seconds.

```
var validDateTimeFormats = new[]
{
   "d/MM/yyyy",
   "d/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
   "d/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
   "dd/M/yyyy",
   "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm",
   "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
   "d/M/yyyy",
   "d/M/yyyy HH:mm",
   "d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
   "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
   "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
};

DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeStr, validDateTimeFormats,
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
   // My logic
}
```

Comment: You don't need the dd and MM combinations. Leave only the d/M it works also with double digit days/months

Comment: Elegant is in the eye of the beholder. I think what you have is good; it's obvious what formats are valid, and your `TryParseExact` is basically in one line. What more do you want?

Comment: @Steve following your suggestion I managed to reduce the `validDateTiemFormats` to just 3 lines! Happy with that. Thanks

Comment: @Steve, Add your comment as an answer so it can be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Steve for the suggestion. dd and MM combinations are not needed.

**Final code:**

```
var validDateTimeFormats = new[]
{
   "d/M/yyyy",
   "d/M/yyyy HH:mm",
   "d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
};

DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeStr, validDateTimeFormats,
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
   // My logic
}
```

Comment: You can also inlile the `DateTime` declaration: `DateTime.TryParseExact(..... out var dateTime)` and reduce one more line of code.